# Restrict Facebook page notifications to posts that I created (I'm an Editor)

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I've recently been made Editors of a couple of Facebook pages, and get notifications about everything. Is it possible to somehow change the settings so I only get notifications about posts that I have made?

I'm soon going to be an Editor on a dozen or more different popular Facebook pages.

Answer (score 2):

Change the notification settings for a Page you help manage.

From the [Facebook Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/172901342767609):

> When you change your notification settings for a Page you help manage, the notification settings of others who help manage the Page won't be affected. Others who work on the Page will still get notifications about the Page based on the settings they've chosen.
>
> To change your notification settings for a Page:
>
> 1. Click **Settings** at the top of your Page.
> 2. Click **Notifications** in the left column.
> 3. Edit your notification settings.

[This question](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=712140847387) on Facebook Help Center is related.

Comment: I swear those settings weren't there a couple of days ago... I need my eyes testing! Thanks

Comment: It doesn't actually achieve what I requested though, I still have to opt to either get notifications of comments/likes on every post on the page, or on no posts on the page.  I just want the notifications of comments/likes on MY posts on the page.